# how to trim or play a audio from begin time to end time in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, trim

This is similar to the trim function of iTunes,pass two following parameters to get a trim audio that i want.

eg.
begin time:00:23.12

stop time:01:33.54

Much appreciated if any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading this in 2016 and you're looking for a solution.It's working for me(swift 2.3):

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    exporter!.outputURL = soundFile1
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avAsset1.duration)
    print(duration)
    if (duration < 5.0) {
        print("sound is not long enough")
        return
    }
    // e.g. the first 30 seconds
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
    let stopTime = CMTimeMake(30,1)
    let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)
    print(exportTimeRange)
    exporter!.timeRange = exportTimeRange
    print(exporter!.timeRange)
```

Comment: what is exactly 5.0 minute or seconds ??